# Spring MVC interceptor mapping for web application root

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have an Interceptor configured in my application context that i want to map to the root of web application ("/").

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.example.SslInterceptor" />
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/" />
        <mvc:mapping path="/login" />
        <bean class="com.example.SslInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

But while the interceptor is called for "/login" it is not for "/". Please help

Comment: What happens if you reverse the order of the mvc:mapping paths?

Comment: Clarity? Same thing as in the last path / gets called instead or same thing as in /login is called?

Comment: oh..i am sorry, /login works but "/" doesn't

Comment: So If I get you right, if you remove the "/login" completely and just leave the entry for the "/", login works, but "/" doesn't?

Comment: no i was talking about changing the order...not removing anything

Comment: ok... I am not finding anything in the docs about having more than one path, so I'm not sure how much help I can be, but I'll leave you with 2 possible ideas:  (1) Try without /login and see if you can get it to work with the "/" config only. If that works, then it likely doesn't like 2 path declarations. (2) Try mapping 2 completely separate interceptor XML configurations, one for each path. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I found out the syntax for multiple mapping from herehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402757/spring-mvc-sharing-same-interceptor-for-multiple-paths...not sure if spring supports this...will try your suggestions

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors may help too.  Good luck! :)

Comment: yes the syntax for multiple paths is correct..i tried with a path other than "/"..so multiple paths work...but it doesn't map "/"

Comment: Could you redirect '/' to something you can map?  Just an idea....

Comment: i tried this <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home"/>, but it seems this is done after all interceptors are called. So it's not useful for me.

Comment: yes, redirection worked perfectly...thanks...but its surprising there isn't any way of mapping root path to interceptor in spring.

Comment: Sumit, I'm not sure what this would look like, or I'd add it myself, but you should add what worked for you as an actual answer to this question. It's okay to self-answer on SO!

Comment: I would add that as an answer if i don't get any valid answer in reasonable time, but really its just a hack...i am not sure if that would be a valid answer because i wanted to do this directly in the configuration.

Comment: Your mapping is somewhat confusing: with the first entry you map `SslInterceptor` to _any_ path, then you try to map `SslInterceptor` to two distinct paths.

Comment: i am at a loss here, where do I map SslInterceptor to any path?

Comment: My context root is referring to a welcome file under WEB-INF, "/**" working for all url except context root path. I tried "/" but in this case it si not working for any urls. So how do i give path so that my interceptor work for every url including context root path.Please assist.

Answer (score 3):

Please change the interceptors config in the servlet config xml file as following:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<mvc:interceptors>
  <mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
    <bean class="de.scrappy.web.TestInterceptor"/>
  </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to map the root path only or did you mean '/*'?
Anyway, the following configuration works for me using Spring 3.1.1, the DispatcherServlet is mapped to root ('/') in web.xml:

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<mvc:interceptors>
  <mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/"/>
    <bean class="de.scrappy.web.TestInterceptor"/>
  </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Which Version of Spring are you using and how is Spring's DispatcherServlet mapped?
And note that `TestInterceptor` implements `HandlerInterceptor`, I don't know if `WebRequestInterceptors` are handled differently.